# node-nock mocking a uri with a question mark in the path

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

I am trying to mock a path which contains a question mark but is not part of a query string, for example:

`https://example.com/index.php?/api/v2/get-item/1`

Nock is slicing the path at the question mark and expecting me to supply query string key-value pairs:

```
const scope = nock('https://example.com/index.php?/api/v2/get-item/')
  .get('/1')
  .reply(200, { item });

console.log(nock.activeMocks());

> [ 'GET https://example.com/index.php/1' ]
```

I have tried URI encoding the path but I still have the same problem. What is the best approach here?

Comment: remove the question mark by yourself. Use String.replace. Such URLS are invalid as per protocol.

Comment: The URL is a third party dependency. Take a look at the docs here: http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/reference-suites
I dont know if this is a php or testrail thing?

Comment: Does the existing answer help or you still need help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the hostname only in the `nock` call. As of right now, you're including some of the path there, and some of it in the `get` call.

Do this instead:

```
const scope = nock('https://example.com')
  .get('/index.php?/api/v2/get-item/1')
  .reply(200, { item });
```

Comment: Agreed!!     Examples at https://github.com/node-nock/nock#specifying-hostname explains it all